# getting other values from a json data by inputting other values in the array

Tags: javascript

i have following `json` data

from this i have name `'iPhone 4s'.`

but while inputing the name `'iPhone 4s'` how can i get the corresponding values of `host` and `target`.am using `javascript`

```
{
    devices: [
        {
            name: 'iPhone 4s',
            host: '3.175: 375',
            target: '137fc82506eb75431ec96fdd'
        },
        {
            name: 'iPhone 5s',
            host: '19:7265',
            target: 'ea4c19957bbba6980db0f7'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Here you can find number of options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects for finding an object in array by property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript provide JSON.parse(); for parsing json data.

You can save your response in variable.

```
var response=JSON.parse(data);
```

Then use the all value from it's key.

```
var name = response.devices[0].name;
var host = response.devices[0].host;
var target = response.devices[0].target;
```

These code only get the 1st array element values. Using for loop you can get get all values from devices array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);

data.devices.forEach(function(device) {
    if(device.name === 'iPhone 4s') {
        console.log(device.name, device.host, device.target);
    }
});

// 'iPhone 4s', '3.175: 375', '137fc82506eb75431ec96fdd'
```